# Image doesn't load from wwwroot if I'm using path base

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My app is being hosted on:

`hxxps://myserver(dot)com/`

I have an image in `wwwroot/images/picture.jpg`

I'm using
`app.UsePathBase("appPrefix")`

and now I'm using `<img src="/images/picture.jpg />` in `.cshtml` file

the problem is that image is actually located under

`hxxps://myserver(dot)com/appPrefix/images/picture.jpg`

but `img` tries to get it from `hxxps://myserver(dot)com/images/picture.jpg`

Thus, how can I tell (probably) ViewEngine that he should respect `PathBase`?

Comment: Have you tried using `<img src="~/images/picture.jpg" />` (with the `~`)?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to add `<base href="/appPrefix"/>` to your _Layout.cshtml file in the head-section.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Is it possible to inject app's pathbase to layout.cshtml? or I gotta use global variable

Comment: As the [extensionmethod UsePathBase](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UsePathBaseExtensions.cs) seems to not store the PathBase in the DI-Chain I am afraid it is not possible. I'd suggest to create a configuration object that holds the path as a property that you can add to your Services as Singleton. Then you should be able to inject this one in the _Layout.cshtml.